# Como ler valores de uma tabela html com js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Possuo uma tabela `tbLista` em html com alguns valores preenchidos e queria ler ela pelo JS, meu codigo Js está da seginte forma:

```
    var rowIndex = -1;
var beneficiarios = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formCadastro').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var lista = document.getElementById('tbLista').rows;    
        for (var i = 1; i < lista.length; i++) {
            beneficiarios.push(JSON.stringify({ "cpf": lista[i].cells[0].innerHTML, "nome": lista[i].cells[1].innerHTML }));
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: urlPost,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "NOME": $(this).find("#Nome").val(),
                "CEP": $(this).find("#CEP").val(),
                "Email": $(this).find("#Email").val(),
                "Sobrenome": $(this).find("#Sobrenome").val(),
                "Nacionalidade": $(this).find("#Nacionalidade").val(),
                "Estado": $(this).find("#Estado").val(),
                "Cidade": $(this).find("#Cidade").val(),
                "Logradouro": $(this).find("#Logradouro").val(),
                "Telefone": $(this).find("#Telefone").val(),
                "Cpf": $(this).find("#Cpf").val(),
                "Beneficiarios": JSON.stringify(beneficiarios)
            },
            error:
                function (r) {
                    if (r.status == 400)
                        ModalDialog("Ocorreu um erro", r.responseJSON);
                    else if (r.status == 500)
                        ModalDialog("Ocorreu um erro", "Ocorreu um erro interno no servidor.");
                },
            success:
                function (r) {
                    ModalDialog("Sucesso!", r)
                    $("#formCadastro")[0].reset();
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CpfBeneficiario">CPF:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CpfBeneficiario" name="CpfBeneficiario" placeholder="Ex.: 010.011.111-00" maxlength="14">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NomeBeneficiario">Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NomeBeneficiario" name="NomeBeneficiario" placeholder="Ex.: João" maxlength="50">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button id="btnIncluir" type="button" onclick="AddBeneficiarios();" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="margin-top: 45%">Incluir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<table id="tbLista" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("CPF")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Nome")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>        
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Como fazer?

Comment: sem mostrar o html não vai dar pra ajudar

Comment: poste todo seu código assim conseguimos te ajudar melhor, abraço

Comment: @RicardoPontual Postado o HTML

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está usando `jQuery`, então não precisa misturar algumas coisas como essa linha:
 `var lista = document.getElementById('tbLista').rows;`, que pode simplesmente ser assim:
 `var lista = $('#tbLista').rows;`.

Quanto a ler as linhas, cada `td` dentro da row pode ser lida com um índice, por exemplo `$(tr).find('td:eq(0)')` é a primeira, e assim por diante. Sugiro que use algo mais acertivo, como uma classe, por exemplo `$(tr).find('.td-cpf')`, mas não sei como gerou a tabela, então vou deixar com o posicional, que funciona assim:

```js
var beneficiarios = [];

var lista = $('#tbLista tbody');  

$(lista).find("tr").each(function(index, tr) {
   
   beneficiarios.push(JSON.stringify({ "cpf": $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').html(), "nome": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').html() }))
});

console.log(beneficiarios);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbLista" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                CPF
            </th>
            <th>
                Nome
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>João</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Maria</td>
  </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Veja que pra pegar o conteúdo da `td` usei `.html()`